# Implement auto log-off feature in Iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am making an application which logs in using some username and password. Now when i am logged in succesfully I want my application to be logged out automatically if no interaction with the application found for 10-12 minutes.

Can anybody guide me how can i achieve this ??

Help with some code will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Thing you want to implement is called SESSION MANAGEMENT.You have to subclass the UIApplication.

```
@interface MyUIApp : UIApplication {

}
```

In this class you have to reset the timer each time. Also you have to check if the application is responded or not with this.If the idleTimer is Exceeded then push the viewController to your login view.

```
 - (UIResponder *)nextResponder {
    [self resetIdleTimer];
    return [super nextResponder];
}
```

Also you have to change the main class file with this:-

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    NSString* appClass = @"MyUIApp";
    NSString* delegateClass = nil;


    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, appClass, delegateClass);

    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```